# Bash, look for pattern, prepend match with #, insert new string below

Tags: bash

As the subject says, I'm trying to come up with a good way of updating a configuration file using bash. The plan is to look for a pattern, prepend any matches with #, and then insert a new string below. For example

file before:

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3
```

Bash to update key2, make key2=test

file after:

```
key1=value1
#key2=value2
key2=test
key3=value3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a bash script to do that

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i -r -e "s/^($2)=(.*)$/#$2=\2\n$2=$3/" $1
```

You could then use it like this to perform your example:

```
./update configfile key2 test
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed '/key2/{ s/^/#/; a\
key2=test
}' input
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a party until you do it in `awk`

```
awk '$0 ~ key{$0="#" $0 "\n" key "test"}1' key="key2=" infile
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
cat <<! >changes.txt
> key2=test
> !
sed 's|\([^=]*\).*|/^\1/s/.*/#\&\\n&/|' changes.txt | sed -i -f - file
cat file
key1=value1
#key2=value2
key2=test
key3=value3
```